# Neo4J query performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relatively small graph (2.5M nodes, 5M rel, 7.7M properties) and I am executing (what seems to me) a simple query but it's taking 63 seconds to execute on a fast SSD-based laptop. Is this really the performance I should expect from Neo4j, or is there anything wrong with the query?

```
start ph=node(2)
match ph-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->c
where c.tag = "class 1"
with c
match c-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->p<-[:SOLD]-l<-[:LINE]-h-[:SOLD_IN]->s
return s.tag as store, sum(l.item_quantity) as quantity order by s.tag;
```

[image: console output]

**Update:** Just wanted to post the updated query:

```
start ph=node(2)
match ph-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->c-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->p<-[:SOLD]-l<-[:LINE]-h-[:SOLD_IN]->s
where c.tag = "class 1"
with s.tag as store, sum(l.item_quantity) as quantity
return store, quantity order by store;
```

[image: console with updated query]

Comment: That's not that small for running on your local machine, and please define further what you mean by "fast" because it doesn't matter if you've got an SSD hard drive if you've got 512 Megs of DRAM.

Comment: 6 GB RAM, but maybe I am underestimating the graph size. I'll run the test on a server with better specs and report the results.

Comment: This is Odd. So i am running this on a 2 Xeon server with 24GB RAM and 15K drives in Raid 5, and the query returns SLOWER than on my laptop (52 seconds vs. 2.3). The recommended specs based on Neo4j calc are 4 cores and 7GB RAM. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Gil You should probably ask a new question asking why your query performance is different between the two machines. That question is outside the scope of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a specific use case, you should usually try removing the `WITH` clause to boost performance.

```
start ph=node(2)
match ph-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->c-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->p<-[:SOLD]-l<-[:LINE]-h-[:SOLD_IN]->s
where c.tag = "class 1"
return s.tag as store, sum(l.item_quantity) as quantity order by s.tag;
```

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, we can get even better performance by forcing the `ORDER BY` to happen after aggregation instead of before. We can do this by using `WITH` (so there's that specific use case we were just talking about). The difference here is that we've moved the `WITH` clause as far to the end as possible, allowing all previous processing to be grouped together rather than separated.

```
start ph=node(2)
match ph-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->c-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->p<-[:SOLD]-l<-[:LINE]-h-[:SOLD_IN]->s
where c.tag = "class 1"
with s.tag as store, sum(l.item_quantity) as quantity
return store, quantity order by store;
```

Comment: Thanks. Took it down to 37 seconds which is better, but still high.

Comment: @Gil Agreed, still very high. Out of curiosity, can you try removing the `ORDER BY` just to see if it has any significant impact on performance? Also, how many rows are returned if you remove the `sum()`, so that your return clause is just `return s.tag as store, l.item_quantity`?

Comment: ok, without the Order By it's down to 3 seconds! The number of rows returned after removing the sum() is 107,153. Is there a better way of doing Order By?

Comment: You might try to lookup c as indexed node: start c=node:tags(tag="class 1") match c-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->...

Comment: you can try to do: `WITH s.tag as store, sum(l.item_quantity) as quantity RETURN store, quantity order by store`

Comment: @Gil I think Michael is right. Contrary to what I just said about removing `WITH` wherever possible, I think in this case it could help you. I **think** what is happening is that neo4j is ordering the results before doing the aggregation (which means it is ordering 107k rows). If you use a `WITH` and then order by something in the `WITH` as Michael suggested, it should do the aggregation first before the order.

Comment: @MichaelHunger: With the index it comes back in 7 seconds.

Comment: @ean5533: ok, much better. The following query returned in 2.3 seconds
start ph=node(2)
match ph-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->c-[:NEXT_LEVEL]->p<-[:SOLD]-l<-[:LINE]-h-[:SOLD_IN]->s
where c.tag = "class 1"
with s.tag as store, sum(l.item_quantity) as quantity
return store, quantity order by store;

I still worry how this will scale. My final graph will have 600M+ nodes...

Comment: If you remember, update this question when your graph is near it's final size, or do a blog post. That's a bigger graph than I have built and I would like to know the story.